# .NET 6 Framework Code based configuration connection string setting

Tags: configuration, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0, connection-string, dbcontext

After .NET 6 Framework update we get [code based configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/code-based), which allows to push `IDbConnectionFactory`  to `SetDefaultConnectionFactory`. Here

```
public class DatabaseConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public DatabaseConfiguration()
        {
            SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());
            SetDefaultConnectionFactory(connectionFactory: new LocalDbConnectionFactory("mssqllocaldb"));
        }
    }
```

There is `CreateConnection` method in `IDbConnectionFactory` which takes `string nameOrConnectionString`. Here

```
public DbConnection CreateConnection(string nameOrConnectionString)
        {
            Check.NotEmpty(nameOrConnectionString, "nameOrConnectionString");
            string arg = " ";
            return new SqlConnectionFactory(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Data Source=(localdb)\\{1};{0};{2}", _baseConnectionString, _localDbVersion, arg)).CreateConnection(nameOrConnectionString);
        }
```

The question is - where is connection string configured?

Before i managed that with npgsql like that `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => { options.UseNpgsql(connectionString); });`, but now the configuration is implicit, can't find where should i put connection string.

In my case i try to start net app with npgsql provider (for postgresql database). Its very similar to microsoft example

```
public class DatabaseConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public DatabaseConfiguration()
        {
            var name = "Npgsql";
            SetProviderFactory(providerInvariantName: name, providerFactory: NpgsqlFactory.Instance);
            SetProviderServices(providerInvariantName: name, provider: NpgsqlServices.Instance);
            SetDefaultConnectionFactory(connectionFactory: new NpgsqlConnectionFactory());
        }
    }
```

And `CreateConnection` method

```
public DbConnection CreateConnection(string nameOrConnectionString)
        {
            return new NpgsqlConnection(nameOrConnectionString);
        }
```

But still have no ideas about connection strings